# Micro-USB smartphone dock with AUX output and ethernet

Tags: smartphones, android, docking-stations

I used a Freecom Musicpal as bedroom radio and alarm clock, but it died after 14 years of usage.

Now I'm looking for a replacement and thought about using an old Android Smartphone because it has an in-built alarm clock that supports multiple alarms, and an integrated music player app.

There is a 2.1 sound speaker system in the bedroom that I would like to connect and thus need a 3.5mm AUX output, and ideally an ethernet port so I can disable WiFi and use cabled network to play music from the local file server.

So I'm looking for a smartphone dock that exposes a micro USB connector I can plug my old smartphone into, and that acts as USB hub for AUX output and ethernet.

---

I found some cheap micro usb smartphone docks on Amazon, but none that do more than delivering power to the phone.

Comment: How opposed would you be to replacing the phone with one with USB-C? There's tons of cheap USB-C phones, and it's way easier to find USB-C hubs with ethernet/3.5mm outputs.